# Headers in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, linux-headers

I am trying to install the Linux headers like this:

```
apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r) gcc make acpid dkms libglvnd-core-dev libglvnd0 libglvnd-dev dracut
```

However, I have this error:

```
Package 'linux-headers-5.14.14-051414-generic' has no installation candidate.
```

What can I do?

Comment: let me guess mainline Kernel? https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.14.14/

Comment: I used uname -r and shows me this: 5.14.14-051414-generic.

Comment: It looks like you are already on up to date kernel So why you want a new one ?

Comment: @AkshajSingla I want to use Nvidia x Server to use my graphic card, from the integrated GPU to the dedicated GPU and the Nvidia see nothing

Comment: Which version of headers do you want ? Plz specify it for eg 5.4 , 5.13 etc .

Comment: @AkshajSingla the 5.14.14-051414-generic version

Comment: You said that uname -r output as 5.14.14-051414-generic So it means you are already on that kernel , Also it means that you are not having an official kernel because 20.04 uses 5.4 kernel So that can be a cause for the issue with Nvidia

Comment: Probably try downloading 5.4 kernel BTW what are the specs of your pc ?

Comment: @AkshajSingla AMD Ryzen 7 4800H with Radeon Graphics; 16GB RAM, Nvidia GeForce 1650

Comment: Ok then try running this command to get the best kernel for your system - ```sudo apt install linux-generic``` and then boot into it and see if problem is solved

Comment: Also Don't use kernel 5.14 (As per my recommendation) Because it doesn't support much Ubuntu 20.04 specs

Comment: ```sudo ubuntu-drivers devices``` This command may help too.

Comment: Also maybe this is a driver issue ```sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-$VERSION``` To get latest Nvidia drivers , change version with the version you want (press tab key 2 times to see available versions ) or replace it by 440

Comment: If these don't work post the output of ```lspci | egrep -i "vga|display|3d"```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a mainline kernel, not an Ubuntu kernel.

You can't install headers for it from Ubuntu repositories.

You need to install headers from the place you got the kernel image files.

Nvidia drivers are unlikely to build against the newest mainline kernel.

Comment: ok... thank you!

Comment: yikes, really? My wifi won't work without it :(